# Compose ExposedDropdownMenu system bar issue in edge to edge

Tags: android, android-layout, android-jetpack-compose, insets

[image]

I have a list of ExposedDropdownMenus and an edge-to-edge state of app implemented by using insets.

```
WindowInsetsControllerCompat(window, bindingActivity.root).let { controller ->
            controller.hide(WindowInsetsCompat.Type.systemBars())
            controller.systemBarsBehavior = WindowInsetsControllerCompat.BEHAVIOR_SHOW_TRANSIENT_BARS_BY_SWIPE
        }
```

When i click on dropdown menu item, navigation bar become visible and an item calculating up or down should drop out, lagging at specific position where navbar height pushed it to opens up instead of down (penultimate on GIF). So how can i disable appearence of navbar while clicking on ExposedDropdownMenus?